# HTML select options filtered while opened on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a very strange issue with Google Chrome and rendering the select options.

What am I doing: I click the select, the options open, while the options are open an AJAX is run and based on the results the list is filtered.

All goes well the first time. The second time, the filtered result shows only after I close the select and reopen it.

With the developer tool I could see that the HTML was changed, but not the view.

I use AngularJS 1.2 with ng-options, also tried with ng-repeat.

Do you have any idea why Chrome is not rendering the correct options and what CSS-JS technique to use? I would prefer a solution with AngularJS or jQuery. Or is it hopeless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally to avoid the problem I used angularJs multiselect. As I read over the internet many people solve many problems regarding the select html tag by just using plugins that redefine the select as an ul list and control the visuals with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

did you try opening it in a different browser?